# Py.test in eclipse throws AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, pytest, pydev

I have a simple python test

```py
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def test_inc_pass():
    assert inc(5) == 6
    
def test_inc_fail():    
    assert inc(5) == 5
```

And when i'm trying to run those tests using py.test runner directly from eclipse, then I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MojeApps\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.6.0.202006041357\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 273, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\MojeApps\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.6.0.202006041357\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 265, in main
    return pytest.main(argv)
AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'main'
```

I've already tried to reinstall pytest with:

```
> pip uninstall pytest
> pip install pytest
```

but nothing helped. Interestingly when i'm running tests from CMD/command line - everything works fine.

```
C:\Development\eclipse_workspace\PySandbox\pytest>pytest
========================================================================= test session starts ==========================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-6.0.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Development\eclipse_workspace\PySandbox\pytest
plugins: pydev-0.1.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                       

test_sample.py .F                                                                                                                                                 [100%]

=============================================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________ test_inc_fail _____________________________________________________________________________

    def test_inc_fail():
>       assert inc(5) == 5
E       assert 6 == 5
E        +  where 6 = inc(5)

test_sample.py:9: AssertionError
======================================================================= short test summary info ========================================================================
FAILED test_sample.py::test_inc_fail - assert 6 == 5
===================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.14s ======================================================================
```

I guess that there must be something with eclipse/pydev.
Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your interpreter configured in PyDev is not the same one you're using in the command line?

-- pytest should definitely have `pytest.main`.

Please run the code below (as a regular launch without unit-testing both from the command line as well as from within Eclipse) and provide the output you have in those cases (it should make clear what's the executable and where `pytest` is being gotten from).

```
import sys

def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def test_inc_pass():
    assert inc(5) == 6

def test_inc_fail():
    assert inc(5) == 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pytest
    print('Running in: %s' % (sys.executable,))
    print('PyTest found in: %s' % (pytest.__file__,))
    pytest.main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing. For the first time, when i run your code from eclipse i got the same error as previously, but after restarting eclipse, i run it one more time and Your code works fine:

```
Running in: C:\MojeApps\Python365\python.exe
PyTest found in: C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pytest\__init__.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-6.0.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Development\eclipse_workspace\PySandbox\pytest_so_help
collected 2 items

main.py .F                                                               [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_inc_fail ________________________________

    def test_inc_fail():
>       assert inc(5) == 5
E       assert 6 == 5
E        +  where 6 = inc(5)

main.py:10: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED main.py::test_inc_fail - assert 6 == 5
========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.03s =========================
```

and running "my tests" via eclipse gives me new error :)

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-6.0.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Development\eclipse_workspace\MyPyTests\src
collected 2 items

tests\test_sample.py .F
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 240, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 296, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 321, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 100, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 117, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 211, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     hook.pytest_runtest_logreport(report=report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\Python365\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.6.0.202006041357\pysrc\_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py", line 265, in pytest_runtest_logreport
INTERNALERROR>     exc = _get_error_contents_from_report(report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\MojeApps\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.6.0.202006041357\pysrc\_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py", line 167, in _get_error_contents_from_report
INTERNALERROR>     tw = TerminalWriter(stringio=True)
INTERNALERROR> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stringio'

========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.05s =========================
```

I'm starting to think that pydev plugin is broken...

EDIT:
Weird thing. After the night when I booted OS, and check if it still appears - it suddenly started to work without a problem - I have no idea...